# How to deal with log of zero in R in image.plot?

Tags: r

I have a matrix, and the entries are all probabilities. Most of the entries have very low probabilities. Some have zeros. I need to do log of the matrix. However, since there are zeros in the matrix, R generates -inf for those zero entries. My goal is to feed this log(matrix) into the image.plot(). When I feed this into the image.plot, I kept getting this error:

```
Error in seq.default(minz + binwidth/2, maxz - binwidth/2, by = binwidth) : 
  invalid (to - from)/by in seq(.)
```

Is there any solution in here that can help me get around this?

Here is what the matrix looks like:

```
                  0          1          2          3         4         5         6
 [1,] -0.0007854138 -8.9132811 -10.011893 -10.705041 -9.606428 -9.318746      -Inf
 [2,] -0.3402118357 -1.6137090  -2.742625  -4.215836 -5.721434 -7.121522 -9.606428
 [3,] -0.2912175507 -2.0296478  -3.521929  -4.275321 -4.426519 -4.187369 -3.715705
 [4,] -1.5244380532 -0.7048802  -2.001368  -3.405243 -3.713864 -3.143919 -3.781412
 [5,] -0.7572491288 -0.7487709  -3.981208  -5.110329 -5.228577 -5.095569 -5.293395
 [6,] -0.0007629648       -Inf  -8.759130  -7.613998 -9.606428      -Inf      -Inf
 [7,] -0.0020658381 -7.4861648  -7.526987  -7.094123 -9.318746      -Inf      -Inf
 [8,] -0.0295715883 -6.7160566  -7.208533  -6.610696 -6.485533 -6.813220 -6.387552
 [9,] -0.0032128722 -6.7160566  -7.613998  -7.871827 -7.760602 -8.759130 -8.759130
[10,] -0.4869248130 -1.3225132  -2.518576  -3.768698 -5.140520 -6.183252 -7.208533
               7          8          9
 [1,]       -Inf -10.705041 -10.011893
 [2,]       -Inf       -Inf  -7.149693
 [3,]  -4.965248  -5.968842  -6.428374
 [4,]  -4.696227  -5.091913  -4.669559
 [5,]  -5.163777  -5.468599  -6.577906
 [6,]       -Inf       -Inf       -Inf
 [7,]       -Inf       -Inf       -Inf
 [8,]  -6.627503  -6.456545  -6.400976
 [9,] -10.011893 -10.011893       -Inf
[10,]  -8.402456  -7.814669  -6.546158
```

Here is the structure :

```
structure(c(0.999214894571557, 0.71161956034096, 0.747353073126963, 
0.217743382682817, 0.468954688200987, 0.999237326155227, 0.997936294302378, 
0.970861372812921, 0.996792283535218, 0.614513234634365, 0.000134589502018843, 
0.199147599820547, 0.13138178555406, 0.49416778824585, 0.472947510094213, 
0, 0.000560789591745177, 0.00121130551816958, 0.00121130551816958, 
0.266464782413638, 4.48631673396142e-05, 0.0644010767160162, 
0.0295423956931359, 0.135150291610588, 0.0186630776132795, 0.00015702108568865, 
0.00053835800807537, 0.000740242261103634, 0.000493494840735756, 
0.0805742485419471, 2.24315836698071e-05, 0.0147599820547331, 
0.0139075818752804, 0.0331987438313145, 0.00603409600717811, 
0.000493494840735756, 0.000829968595782862, 0.00134589502018843, 
0.000381336922386721, 0.0230820995962315, 6.72947510094213e-05, 
0.00327501121579183, 0.0119560340960072, 0.0243831314490803, 
0.00536114849708389, 6.72947510094213e-05, 8.97263346792284e-05, 
0.00152534768954688, 0.000426200089726335, 0.00585464333781965, 
8.97263346792284e-05, 0.000807537012113055, 0.0151861821444594, 
0.0431135038133692, 0.00612382234185734, 0, 0, 0.00109914759982055, 
0.00015702108568865, 0.00206370569762225, 0, 6.72947510094213e-05, 
0.0243382682817407, 0.022790489008524, 0.00502467474203679, 0, 
0, 0.00168236877523553, 0.00015702108568865, 0.000740242261103634, 
0, 0, 0.00697622252131, 0.00912965455361149, 0.00572005383580081, 
0, 0, 0.00132346343651862, 4.48631673396142e-05, 0.000224315836698071, 
2.24315836698071e-05, 0, 0.00255720053835801, 0.00614625392552714, 
0.00421713772992373, 0, 0, 0.0015702108568865, 4.48631673396142e-05, 
0.000403768506056528, 4.48631673396142e-05, 0.000785105428443248, 
0.00161507402422611, 0.00937640197397936, 0.00139075818752804, 
0, 0, 0.00165993719156572, 0, 0.00143562135486765), .Dim = c(10L, 
10L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
"6", "7", "8", "9")))
```

Comment: Which error message did you get? I think `log()` in R should return `-inf` for 0.0

Comment: An important question is why are you taking the log?

Comment: Because I am in fact working with a very large matrix, but most entries have very very low values. If I simply feed this matrix into image.plot, it is ineffective. Taking log may make the difference betweeen entries more noticeable

Comment: what package `image.plot` is from. What typical values does it expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

True, a log plot may make "the difference betweeen entries more noticeable". However, if you have zeros in your data, you'd be using it wrong. The point of a logarithmic scale is to illustrate exponential increases in the data. Having zeros, however, means that either:

- the values observed were not produced by a process exhibiting exponential
  growth **or**
- you need to handle your missing values differently.

Either way, what would work a lot better in your case is taking the *square root of the values*. Or *(n>2)-th root* if you want to accentuate the difference in values even more -- the higher the *n*, the bigger the difference.

As per @flodel's suggestion below, the code that would do this is: `image.plot(sqrt(x))` or, more generally, `image.plot(x^(1/n))` for some `n>1`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: much better! Worth mentioning that the R code would be `image.plot(x^(1/n))` for some `n > 1`.

Answer (score 4):

If these zeros are caused by a physical measurement which should yield a positive-definite results but fails to do so for technical reasons, it might be reasonable to substitute 1/2 of the lower limit of detection for the zeros.

```
 M2 <- M
 print( min(M[M!=0]), digits=16)
#[1] 2.24315836698071e-05
 M2[M2==0] <- 0.5*min(M[M!=0])
 image(M2)
 image(log(M2))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A simple trick is to add 1 since log1=0 such that cell with 0 still will have 0 after log transformation.

```
  k<-matrix(c(1:8,0,0),nrow=2,ncol=5)

> k
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    3    5    7    0
[2,]    2    4    6    8    0
log(k)
          [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4] [,5]
[1,] 0.0000000 1.098612 1.609438 1.945910 -Inf
[2,] 0.6931472 1.386294 1.791759 2.079442 -Inf

log(k+1)
          [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4] [,5]
[1,] 0.6931472 1.386294 1.791759 2.079442    0
[2,] 1.0986123 1.609438 1.945910 2.197225    0
```

Comment: Given the OP's input structure, something like `image.plot(log(1 + 10000*x))` gives a nicer picture but good luck interpreting the results... Have my +1 though.

Comment: log(x+1) wouldn't accentuate the difference between the OPs values enough. log(10000x + 1) works significantly better but is still not scale-invariant and may not work if the differences between the values are much smaller than 1/10000.

Answer (score 2):

The except is thrown by `seq()`, which can not take `-inf` as any one of its arguments. You can get exactly the same type of error with the following code:

```
> seq(-log(0), 0, 50)
Error in seq.default(-log(0), 0, 50) : invalid (to - from)/by in seq(.)
```

To avoid it, follow @Metrics 's trick. Although I will suggest instead of adding 1.0, add a very small value, such as 1e-22, since your matrix is a matrix of probabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Can't paste multiple lines of code in a comment, but this example shows what I meant:

```
> m=cbind(c(0,0.88,0.99),c(1,2,1),c(3,4,5))
> m=as.matrix(m)
> log(m)
            [,1]      [,2]     [,3]
[1,]        -Inf 0.0000000 1.098612
[2,] -0.12783337 0.6931472 1.386294
[3,] -0.01005034 0.0000000 1.609438
> m
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] 0.00    1    3
[2,] 0.88    2    4
[3,] 0.99    1    5
```

Comment: It is possible that the exception was not thrown by `log()`, but by what you do next, such as `image.plot()`